# In Squid Game, how did they guarantee a winner for the glass bridge "game"?

Tags: plot-explanation, squid-game

So I'm re-watching Squid Game and I'm trying to figure out something with the glass bridge sub-game.  How did they know that someone would survive the sub-game?  At that point of the series/episodes, there are

> 16

players but I counted

> 18

glass panels.  It's possible that there will be no survivors if they choose incorrectly.  Did I miss something earlier or are the game keepers content with someone not winning that year's Squid Game?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On average, if they play well, each player will move two squares. This is because there's a fifty fifty chance of success. This means you would expect them to, most of the time, be able to move about 32 squares.

The probability of [16 failures](https://blog.evlabs.io/2021/10/16/succeed-at-the-squid-game-glass-bridge-using-statistics/) is 0.065612%, which is low enough that it's unlikely to happen unless they have thousands of games.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's a 99.93% chance that at least one would survive, assuming they each took a guess. In the actual game, there were some players who died without eliminating any wrong panels, so that decreases the probability a little bit, and they would have wanted at least two survivors to have a sixth game, but it's not the games were about playing it safe in the first place. If they ended up not having a sixth game, that wouldn't be the end of the world, and it would give more tension to future games. And given that they turned down the lights, they weren't opposed to interfering, so they could have stopped the game if a lot of people were eliminated.

Comment: You might want to include one of the MANY articles describing the math behind this.  For example https://blog.evlabs.io/2021/10/16/succeed-at-the-squid-game-glass-bridge-using-statistics/.  Someone not familiar with probability might not realize the chance of all 16 players falling is actually quite low. They may even choose a length of bridge to suit their ideal number of players going into the last game.